# Reading integers into a ADT from stdin

Tags: c, list, data-structures, struct, typedef

This is my abstract data structure

```
 typedef struct {
    int *items;
    int size;
 } List;
```

I would like the user to enter integers on a single line such as

```
  a.out 
  12 14 2 8 9
```

and read them into the List. I understand how to add to a list, i guess the thing i don't get is getting the integers from a single line input

Edit: Sorry but I meant using something like scanf not with command line arguments

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Definition of your `main` should be `int main(int argc,char **argv)`

**2.** The numbers will command line arguments (check value of `argc` greater than `1` before using `argv` ).

**3.** `argv[1]` , `argv[2]` will have these numbers , but as string .

**4.** Convert these to integers using `atoi` or `sscanf` functions and store in structure members as you desire.

### EDIT

> Edit: Sorry but I meant using something like scanf not with command line arguments

You can use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) , tokenize string using [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and then convert and store into integer variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use input arguments like:

Your main function will look like: int main (int argc, char *argv[] )

In this case you can add your argument at command line as you would

./a.out 12 14 2 8 9

And you can access those argument by argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], ...

and you can loop over the number of arguments the user provided which is contained in the argc variable

example to access the first argument:

int i;

i= atoi(argv[1]);

Comment: Sorry dude I messed up my question. I wanted to try this with scanf or fgets not command line args

Comment: try to use scanf_s it's a more secure version

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI Its not portable .

Comment: @ameyCU, I appreciate your comment, is there another solution for the portability and security in the same time for that function, thank you

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI I don't think there is anything wrong with `fgets` or even with `scanf` . But you need to keep checking their return values for success.